# Getting high query throughput out of Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the most out of EF Core that I can with queries that need very high throughput. When I run my asp.net core web app in debug mode, I can achieve ~300 queries/s, if I don't attach a debugger I'm getting ~800 queries/s.

Edit: 1200-1400 queries/s over the network with a single connection.

My database can sustain ~3500 queries/s of the same type, and is barely put under load my entity framework. The device EF Core is running on will have ~10% CPU utilization overall, and only the first 2 threads get used up to ~30% each. The remainder of the available threads seem to go unused.

Edit: If I have multiple connections to my asp.net application, the query throughput goes up significantly, but does end up capping out the first 2 cores, and leaving the remaining 6 alone.

**My query:**

```
PlayerRank existingRank = _context.PlayerRankings.Where(p => p.Date == rank.Date && p.Player == rank.Player && p.World == rank.World).FirstOrDefault();
```

**CPU Utilization:**

[image]

How can I get EF Core to utilize more of my systems resources? It's barely touching the CPU, but it seems like it's maxing out on query throughput, yet my DB isn't even close to being maxed.

I am using the Pomelo MySQL connector.

Comment: Are you also monitoring the disk usage on the SQL box?  I'd suggest disk throughput is likely to be the bottleneck for your query, not the CPU.

Comment: @Mick The CPU is on the asp.net/entity framework box, not the MySQL box. This question is about the performance poof EF core, not MySQL. The database can handle ~4x the load than EF Core is putting on it. This is evident by the 300/s to 800/s jump when debugging is not running, yet cpu usage is about the same. I am wondering my asp.net & EF are capping out on query throughput, yet barely utilizing my processor.

Comment: Does the 3500/s number include the network latency? Running a lot of queries on the box itself is one thing. Doing so from a remote machine, transfering the data back and forth is another. Loading 10 players in a single query can be 10 times faster thatn executing 10 individual queries

Comment: "The database can handle" how do you know? How did you measure this?

Comment: BTW you are using a blocking query and MySQL Connector doesn't offer true asynchronous calls anyway. It fakes them by running the query on a separate thread. You may be saturating the threadpool with calls that do nothing but wait. WIth another database you could try `FirstOrDefaultAsync`. That would release the request thread while waiting for a response. That helps *a lot* when you have a lot of small queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I got that number via mysqlslap for a single connection, it was ran locally. Though the DB and the asp.net server are on the same ESXi host, I am getting a ping of 0.3ms via hrPing.  Good to know about the blocking, I may try spinning up workers and see what happens. I am unsure as to why I am not doing bulk selects, I was before, but was having worse performance issues with it. I'll have to revisit that again to get a solid answer.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell that numbers doesn't mean anything then. It doesn't take into account locking or latency. Running on the same host doesn't mean that *networking* is faster or has better latency. Older hosts had higher latency than actual network connections. Finally, if a `Where PlayerID in (...)` or `Date between ... ` is slow, you should check why, not assume that the SELECT statement is slow. Most likely, you are missing indexes on the query columns, or use inappropriate indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The 3500/s number is for that exact query, the table is indexed...etc. Let's go back to running with a debugger attached, at 300 queries/s, at about the same CPU usage. We already know that we can do 800 queries/s when a debugger is not attached, so the DB performance and networking is now out of the equation. How do I get EF Core or asp.net to utilize more of the hosts computing resources?

Comment: Why is it out of the equation? The debugger hooks into everything. It adds even *more* delays. Anyway, the local/single connection benchmark is pretty much meaningless, because it's the absolute best case scenario - no contention from other connections, no data transfer. Use a *different* benchmark, running on a *different* VM, that creates a *similar* number of connections and ONLY THEN compare numbers.

Comment: To put it another way, no self-respecting throughput benchmark runs on the database server itself. They run on **multiple** clients (real or simulated) and count the number of queries per *Client* per second.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1200-1400/s from any capable device on my network.

Comment: Which provider are you using? Oracle or Pomelo? Pomelo uses [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) under the hub, which is real async, where Oracle just retrofitted their old MySQL provider to run with EF Core, which runs sync. Also (since its not clear from your question) if you run SQL queries only and not use any of the ORM goodies like LINQ for queries, you'll likely be better of with Dapper

Comment: @Tseng I am using Pomelo. Most of my queries take advantage of LINQ for queries or something similar like in my example. I just did a test with multiple connections to my asp.net application, and the throughput went up significantly, until it capped out my first 2 cores. Other cores seemed to go mostly unused.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Consider joining the performance discussion at https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/126.